# Xcode targets behaving differently

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, target

I have created two targets in my Xcode project. I have a table view in the project, populated with a custom table view cell with multiple labels in it. When I run one of my target builds, the table view cell populates correctly. But when I run the other target build, one of the labels in the table view cell does not display.

Has anyone else had a problem like this? If so, where should I start looking to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check all files .m and .xib added to all targets